# DMA UART Buffer pointer

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, hal, stm32f4

I'm using a STM32F4 for receiving data from a FPGA (now it only relays data from a PC) using DMA UART. The DMA UART is working as it should, but it can only give an interrupt when the buffer for the UART it is half full or full. The problem is that I want to know if I got new data in the buffer without it being half or full.

In short I am looking for a register which point to where the next byte from the UART should go in the DMA buffer. Does anyone know of a register like that.

Thank you!

Comment: The STM32F4 datasheet should know...

Comment: The number of transfers in the DMA registers shows if you had any transfers and using the simple arithmetic where the pointer in the buffer is. with the DMA interrupts it gives you all the information needed

Comment: You wont be able to read byte-by-byte using DMA. Only wait for the data and parse data in buffer after timeout or full buffer. If you need read data by every byte, then use IT. That is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I found what I was looking for.

```
uint32_t bytesRx DMA1_Stream1->NDTR;
```

and

```
UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;
uint32_t bytesRx = huart3.hdmarx->Instance->NDTR;
```

Both of them works for finding how many bytes that have been received, observe that `NDTR` counts down.

Answer (score 2):

The DMA has a CNDTR register (be aware that it counts down)

Comment: Avoid to share the link as answer, as link may not be available in future. Kindly provide the details here and for a reference purpose, you can share the link

Answer (score 0):

Do you use HALs?
We use this code to know how many bytes we've received:

```
UART_HandleTypeDef              *pHandleUart;
(...)
static uint8_t Uart_RxBufferPointerCheck(void)
{
    uint8_t returnValue = 0;

    rxUartBuffer.last = ( (uint16_t)UART_MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH - Uart_Dma_GetPeripheralNumberOfData() );

    if ( rxUartBuffer.last >= rxUartBuffer.first )
    {
        returnValue = 1;
    }

    return ( returnValue );
}

static uint16_t Uart_Dma_GetPeripheralNumberOfData(void)
{
    return (uint16_t) pHandleUart->hdmarx->Instance->NDTR;
}
```

`rxUartBuffer.first` is modified when we read those bytes.
This code is fo F7 uC, I hope it also works on F4.

Comment: We don't use HAL just for reading NTDR, we use HAL because the development is easier and faster (and then cheaper).

Comment: Disputable. IMO is slower and more expensive especially when you need to find the errors in the library itself (if you take a look into the USB stack implementation or Ethernet for example). Especially the USB stack is one of the best examples how to do not implement it.

Comment: can you provide full code or at least some code since i have been using 196 buffer size and want to read gps data  but i can't think of proper algorithm i have seen lots of methods like this but none of them is perfect can you provide at least how to read exactly the way you explain regarding available

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to poll and check the serial Rx buffer for data or check the value of **hdmarx->Instance->CNDTR** if changed from the default value of buffer size.

The second option would be to use an IDLE interrupt to know if data is received, this can be done by adding a few lines in **HAL_UART_IRQHandler**

```
if((__HAL_UART_GET_IT(huart, UART_IT_IDLE) != RESET) && (__HAL_UART_GET_IT_SOURCE(huart, UART_IT_IDLE) != RESET))
{ 
    __HAL_UART_CLEAR_IT(huart, UART_CLEAR_IDLEF);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried to look your part up, but only found marketing pages.   To get what you want, disable the DMA.   The purpose in the DMA is to lessen the interrupt load, and perhaps maintain a wire rate stream if your cpu can’t keep up with the interrupt rate.   Since you want the interrupt for notification, the DMA is sorta pointless.   Worse, it is keeping you from seeing the interrupt.

Often US?ARTs have an on-board fifo, which alleviates the interrupt rate somewhat, while letting you synchronize with the beginning of a burst or whatever your purpose is.

Comment: Do you actually know this micro to advise anything?